# Wireless mic receiver in a flight case

Tags: wireless

I'm assembling a PA system that has to be portable, so I'm installing everything in flightcases.

I have two Sennheiser EW100 G2 receivers, which have antennas on the back of the unit so the antennas end up in the center of the flightcase. I'm a bit worried about receiver range, though I haven't tested this setup yet.

The same flightcase will also contain a Behringer XR18 and a wifi access point, so that's a potential complication (although the frequencies are far enough apart that they shouldn't bite each other).

Will this setup be ok, or should I look at external antennas for the EW100s?